# Connection problems using Windows Azure hosting

Tags: .net, sql-server, exception, azure

When I connect to SQL Azure from my ASP.NET MVC Application, I get the following error..

> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

But, I am able to connect to SQL Azure from SQL Server Management Studio successfully. I also tried connecting using sqlCMD and that connects without any issue. Only issue arises is during runtime when I get this exception.

Comment: Show us your connection string (if it contains a password change it to ****** before posting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be something wrong with your connection string. You can't connect to Windows Azure SQL Database (a.k.a. SQL Azure) via Named Pipes. The only supported protocol is TCP. So your conn string would look something like:

> Server=tcp:[servername].database.windows.net,1433;Database=[db_name];User
>   ID=[username]@[servername];Password=[password];Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection
>   Timeout=30

You can get connection string from the management portal. When you go to the database, you have the Connection string link at the right (new portal):

[image: SQL Azure show connection strings (new portal)]

And the old portal almost the same:

[image: SQL Azure Connection Strings old portal]

And finally, you must have enabled "Allow other Windows Azure Services to connect to this server" in the Firewall rules.

**** UPDATE according to comments below ****

And where is this connection string entry? IN web.config, or in web.release.config / web.debug.config. Note that web.config transformations will not work for while developing, only when packaging! Does this error occurs when you debug locally, or when you deploy?

If locally, can you check which connection string are you actually using?

Note that there is default "ApplicationServices" connection string (which is in apphost.config), which might take place when you try to "login/register" in the default MVC app! That connection string assumes local SQL Express instance is present and running. And this is default connection string for Memebership and Role providers. You will not be able to logn/register and whatever action that requires authentication, unless you change the Membership provider settings.

Comment: My connection string:          

<add connectionString="Server=tcp:server.database.windows.net,1433; Database=mydatabase; User ID=user@server; Password=myPassword; Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout = 30"
name="mvcappconn" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: I'm changed the connection string, but occurs the same error:

Comment: did you enable other Windows Azure services to connect to this server in the Firewall rules (my last sentence) ?

Comment: yes, I have enabled "Allow other Windows Azure Services to connect to this server"

Comment: my connection string entry in web.config

Comment: please reply to all of my questions in the last update of my answer, in order to help you.

Comment: error occurs within deploying. web.release.config and web.debug.config are not changed...any questions?

Comment: so, the error only happens when you deploy to Windows Azure Cloud Service? And you first hit the page? or when? If so, what code is being executed? Do you access the DB? Via what type? Can you check the connection string being used? In general you shall be able to say which exact connection string is being used in your data access code. you can do some tracing or even HttpRequest.Current.Response.Write("Connstring used: " + mydbObject.connection.connectionstring) or something like that. I am 100% sure that the errors comes from other connectionstring (most likely the ApplicationServices)

Comment: "And you first hit the page?" - YES.
"Do you access the DB?" - YES 
"Via what type?" - Sql server...

In my case, I'm created website from nopcommerce template and published it's to windows azure hosting, but my mvc app is not working.

Comment: Why don't you suspend all running SQL Server instances on your local computer and run the app locally. It will fail and you will debug why exactly that happens. And we will not shooting at the dark. Also a complete stacktrace might show you (us) the point were it really fails - is it our code, is it nopcommerce code, is it the default auth code ..

Comment: I'm found reason. nopcommerce project has a settings.txt file which includes information about dataprovider and conn.string.